# Making a comment to an answer

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

I try to make a comment in answer but I can not. The only availiable box is the answer. 
Am I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have [sufficient Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) to comment everywhere. You need to gain 50 reputation to comment everywhere. But you can comment on your own answer, your question or even on any answer of your question even with 1 reputation.